# C Programming: Creating a Program to Pull Latitude and Longitude from a typedef struct

Tags: c

So I have a project for my class where I need to write a program where the User will type in a City then the program will look up this city from a typedef structure then print that said city's latitude and longitude coordinates. My idea is to take the cities name as an input then somehow compare the city name with the ones in the structure (pointers maybe?) then get the latitude and the longitude when the city matches. I think that I will need to create a loop program to read the data until I find a match. Can you tell me if I am on the right track, or how you would go about writing the program? I attached a small portion of the structure (full one has 200 cities) if someone wants to try it out.

```
  #define MAX_CITY_LEN   35

   typedef struct { 
            char  name[MAX_CITY_LEN];
            float latitude;
            float longitude;
           } PLACE_T;

   PLACE_T places[] =
     {{"Aberdeen,Scotland",57.15,-2.15},
      {"Adelaide,Australia",-34.92,138.6},
      {"Albany,NY,USA",42.67,-73.75},
      {"Albuquerque,NM,USA",35.08,-106.65},
      {"Algiers,Algeria",36.83,3.0},
      {"Amarillo,TX,USA",35.18,-101.83},
```

Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: You are on the right track -- except for your phrasing of "... *somehow* compare the city name ..". Does that mean that you have no (zero, zilch, nada) idea how to do that in C?

Answer (score 1):

do like this:

```
 typedef struct { 
            char  name[MAX_CITY_LEN];
            float latitude;
            float longitude;
 } PLACE_T;

 PLACE_T places[] ={
      {"India,kochi",57.15,-2.15},
      {"Adelaide,Australia",-34.92,138.6},
      {"Albany,NY,USA",42.67,-73.75},
      {"Albuquerque,NM,USA",35.08,-106.65},
      {"Algiers,Algeria",36.83,3.0},
      {"Amarillo,TX,USA",35.18,-101.83},
   };

int main(){
   int j;
  int found=0;
  char city[MAX_CITY_LEN];
  printf("enter city name:");
  fgets(city,MAX_CITY_LEN,stdin);
  city[strlen(city)-1]='\0';
  int citySize=(sizeof(places)/sizeof(places[0]));
  for(j=0;j<citySize;j++){
     if(strcmp(city,places[j].name)==0){
        found=1;                                
        printf("lat = %f, long = %f",places[j].latitude,places[j].longitude); 
        break;                              
     }
   }
   if(!found)
     printf("City not found");

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Question is tagged C, use `printf` and `scanf` instead of `cin` and `cout` ;)

Comment: @Rustam 1) If user types in a name exceeding 35 characters (MAX_CITY_LEN)?  What is the result?  One is lucky if the program crashes.  2) As `gets()` does not prevent user input over-runs, it invites exploitation by hackers. 3) It is no longer available in C11 (i.e. the last 3 years.)

Comment: if `scanf("%s",&city)` it won't read if there is space b/w city name. m i ryt?

Comment: in `scanf("%s",&city)` `&city` or `city` does make any differece? @indiv here `&` is optional

Comment: @indiv nope since i m using `fgets()` which add '\n' too. so to remove the i added that stuff.

Comment: @Rustam `fgets()` is a good solution vs. `gets()`.  Robust code will check the return value of `fgets()` against `NULL`, if the return value if not `NULL`, `city` may be used.  In select  circumstances, `strlen(city) == 0` or the last `char` is not `\n`, so something like `size_t len = strlen(city); if (len > 0 && city[len-1] == '\n') city[--len] = '\0'` may be used to delete the pesky `'\n'`.